# Download File Using URL using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, rest, download, server, nodejs

So I implemented google drive url download feature recently and It starts downloading the publicly shared file directly without any authentication.

When I tried the same with SharePoint, I got 403 error. After further research I found out that I need FedAuth Cookie. There were some articles but all of them needed credentials to do this.

Is there a way to generate FedAuth without credentials since I can download these files without any login through browser but when I try from NodeJS, I get 403 error.